# Change filterToolbar options dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way that i can set `'filterToolbar'` options dynamically?

here is my problem.

1. initially i need a filter according to the search options as - `'defaultSearch : "eq"`
2. after a button click i need to change the search option as - `defaultSearch : "cn"`

   one approach could be set the `defaultSearch` option dynamically ( i don't know weather it is possible) and other would be remove the old `filtertoolbar` and add the new `filtertoolbar` with the defaultsearch as "cn" .

is this possible with the jqgrid? please let me know. appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your question interesting so before all +1 from me.

You can't change the value of `defaultSearch` parameter of `filtertoolbar`, but you can change dynamically:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','name',{searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}});
```

In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DynamicSearchingToolbar.htm) the initial searching option in the 'Client' column defined by `defaultSearch` and is 'cn'. By clicking on two buttons above the grid you can change the option to 'bw' (begin with) or 'ew' (end with). You can easy verify on the demo that the way work.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg. it works. i was wondering how to do it.tried some approaches bt anything didn't come right for me. this is totally different what i thought. Thanks again.. your demos rocks..