# Set default value on filtertoolbar

Tags: jqgrid

I'm looking for a method to set the default value of multiple columns in the filter toolbar with `JSON`.

I know I can use the `defaultvalue` option in searchoptions, but I want to be able to set the filter with a `json string`.

My json string:

```
    {"groupOp":"AND","rules": [{"field":"PART_AFFILIATION","op":"eq","data":"PART-M"},{"field":"STATUS","op":"eq","data":"Active"}]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default operation used in the jqGrid can be defined in the `colModel`. You can use `sopt` property for the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options). The *first* element of the array define the operation for the column. The `defaultSearch` option of the [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#calling_convention) method define the default searching operation only for the column which has no `searchoptions.sopt`.

Comment: But how can I solve this if I got multiple columns and want to load a set of predefined values?

Comment: @f01: Sorry, but I don't full understand your question. If you want to change `searchoptions.sopt` *after* the grid is created you can use `setColProp` for example. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5544472/315935)) for an example.

Comment: I want to be able to load several predefined filter values in my filter toolbar. Here is a json string to show what my input is:
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":
[{"field":"PART_AFFILIATION","op":"eq","data":"PART-M"},{"field":"STATUS","op":"eq","data":"Active"}]}

As you can see I've got two fields I want to update when the grid loads.

Comment: Do you understand me Oleg, or should I write a more describing post?

Comment: @f01: Please be careful with the terminology. You asked in the question about setting of `searchoption`. It is not the same as your last question. The answer on your last question you should find in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981986/315935). [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884755/315935) shows how to fill the filter bar. I recommend you also to read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) and to test [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) which fill filter toolbar from the `localStorage`.

Comment: I have tried setting the postdata as you describe, but I can't seem to get it working. Could you provide a code sample where you put values into the postdata option?

Comment: @f01: Sorry, but I posted you already many links which use definition or modification of `postData` option. The simplest one and the oldest one is [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multisearchfilter.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981986/315935).

Comment: The example you are posting are not using a toolbar at all, so I'm a little confused. I dont got a search form like you, just a toolbar at the top of my grid.

Comment: @f01: What you need to do consist from two steps: 1) setting `postData.filters` (see the previous demo and examples) 2) fill the filter from `postData.filters` in the fields of the toolbar filter. The function `refreshSerchingToolbar` from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884755/315935) shows how to fill the filter bar with the value from `postData.filters`. [The next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) shows even more: it saves/restore **the state of grid** incl. toolbar

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I have now managed to post the filter to the advanced search form, but the search filter wont populate/refresh with my current settings.. I'll try some things out and get back to you.

Comment: I have added my code to the first post. Would you be so kind to review it? I cant get the filter to load in the toolbar.

Comment: @f01: I think that the error is very easy: you used the code from the answer where described how to synchronize advanced searching and the filter toolbar. The problem which you have in the *first* loading of the grid. In the case you call `refreshSearchingToolbar` inside of `loadComplete` *before* the searching toolbar will be created with `filterToolbar`. So you should move the call of `filterToolbar` inside of `loadComplete`, but call it one time. Look at the code from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) inside of `loadComplete`.

Comment: I just tried to move the call to filtertoolbar inside of loadcomplete and still the same result. The filter is loaded to the form, but not to the toolbar..

   loadComplete: function getCurrentFilter() { 
    if (firstLoad) {
     firstLoad = false;
     jQuery("#Jqgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
    }

    refreshSearchingToolbar($(this), myDefaultSearch);
   },

Comment: @f01: Probably you use the filter which can't be represented in the filter toolbar? Look at [one more answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9310762/315935) which uses the technique.