# How to use startwith and between operands in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

I want to use the following start with operand in jqGrid:

```
select * from lib where (mesc.substring(0,2) between 13 and 60)
```

In jqGrid I have just a start with but do not have a start with between, and I would like to add this operand to the search operand.

I have a lib table, and in the lib table I have a mesc field (datatype mesc is nvarchar(10)). In this table I save material information. I group records in the case when Mesc starts with 13 to 60, 6 to 70, and 80 to 90. Possibly the end user would want to see all materials that start with 13 to 16, or 13 to 60. I do not know how to implement this.

Comment: Sorry, but it's absolutely unclear what you mean. If you have database on the server you can generate *any* SQL statement based on parameter which jqGris send. What scenario you use? From where come the constants like 13 and 60? I can continue with unclear questions...

Comment: @Oleg : i Edit Qustion. please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two external `<input>` elements where the user can enter the value for `mesc` field and `<button>` "Search". You can send the values from the filed to the server with every refresh of the grid or by click on the "Search". See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for details.

You can alternatively use only one `<input>` element and allow the user to enter input in the form `13 - 60`. In general you can implement any input options which you need  like [Sliders](http://jqueryui.com/slider/), [Spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) and so on.

You can integrate the external input elements in the top toolbar of jqGrid if you what. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310762/315935) for details.

In any way you can generate any SQL statement based on users input on the server side.

Comment: if want use first solution.you can when user select mesc display tow input?

Comment: @mohsen: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i want use first solution, i want when user click in search icon and disply search box and user select Mesc field display two textbox and user enter data in text box .

Comment: @mohsen: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. stackoverflow is not place where other will develop solution for you for free. It's the place where developers could formulate *question which could be interesting for other*. If another developer could give a tip how to solve some technical problem from the question he write the answer. I don't understand from your previous comment what is your problem and what knowledge in HTML, JavaScript, jQuery, SQL etc you have. Sorry.