# jqGrid Advanced Search + Template Filters with Select "multiple"

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to set some column with search type "< select multiple >" for ADVANCED SEARCH? Plus, I want to create a predefined TmplFilter for that column with multiple values, so the query should be something like: MyColumn IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')

I imagine the template with data array (?) like:
... rules: [{field:"MyColumn", op:"in", data:['X', 'Y', 'Z']}]

And the "< select multiple >" should appear filled with those values pre-selected

(my version is free jqgrid-4.13.6)

==================

EDIT: To be clear, this is an example drawing (not real grid)

[image: Advanced Search + Template Filters with Select Multiple]

What I want is... when click on "Search" button (which opens Advanced Search popup, I know how to use this feature, of course), I want to have some "Templates", when I select one (ie: "With Errors") this will create a rule with Field:"Status", Op:"IN", Data:"Return Errors, Failed Process, Processed No Records" These 3 values must be pre-selected in a combo "multiple" (as you see in the image)

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. One can use `"in"` operation exactly like any other operation. Do you missing an example which uses `tmplFilters` and `tmplNames`? See [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap-tmplFilters.htm) as an example. Do you need some kind of templates displayed in the grid and not in the Searching Dialog? See [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9310762/315935). The code of the answer is old, but the idea is simple: placing "filter"-select in the top toolbar and set `postData.filters` on changing of it.

Comment: @Oleg No, I will try to edit my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting the problem! The problem exists in the usage of `<select>` with `multiple` property in Searching Dialog. I introduced support of `"in"` operation in local searching/filtering in one of the previous version of free jqGrid, but I forgot to include the support of `"in"` operation in searching dialog.

I committed today [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/298fe9bd8e7645841849ff96256a2928191eb21c) to [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). The problem should be solved now. It's important that you either update your local copy of free jqGrid files with the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or you load the latest code from `rawgit.com` (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was a bug, I thought as a simple question, that's because I didn't posted in Github issues. Regards.