# Clear jqgrid toolbar when custom defaultvalue is set

Tags: jqgrid

I want to clear the toolbar of my grid, but not to the default value of the column. I want to empty all fields.

When I use the

```
$("#Jqgrid")[0].clearToolbar();
```

method the toolbar gets the initial default values..

Comment: Could you include the code which set "custom default value" in the toolbar? Then you question will be more clear. What you means under "default value of the column"? Probably more code which you use will be clear all?

Comment: I have defined the following:
searchoptions: curlybracket( defaultValue: "Active" )curlybracket.

When I use the clearToolbar "Active" is set in the filter, but I want "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one from the following two ways.

1) You can temporary change the `defaultValue` of the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options) to "" before call of [clearToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). You can use [setColProp](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method for example to change column properties (see en example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5544472/315935)).

2) Set the value of the the toolbar element manually to "" or to any other value which you want. There are simple way how the ids of the input or select elements of the toolbar are constructed. Let us you have column with the name 'col1' (the corresponding column of `colModel` has `name: 'col1'`). Then the id of the element in the filter toolbar will be `gs_col1`. So you can use

```js
$("#gs_col1").val("");
```

to clear the field. In more general case if the `colname` is the variable which hold the value from `colModel[i].name` you can use

```js
$("#gs_" + $.jgrid.jqID(colname)).val("");
```

Comment: How can I solve this with selects? I cant set the value like I do with textboxes.

Comment: @f01: Do you tried to use the same `$("#gs_col1").val('123');` if you need to select the option with the value `'123'`?

Comment: @f01: See [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/#example-1-2) an example from the documentation of `jQuery.val`.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I got it to work when I moved it out to a function, and then called the function from the reset button..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8294/discussion-between-f01-and-oleg)